# postgreql to_char formatting of a float

Tags: postgresql

I have a float which between 0 and 1, e.g `0.342` or `0.34`, etc. I need this formatted like so: `.XXX`, always three digits precision (with trailing zeroes) and never a leading zero (prior to the decimal. I have this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION format_float(real) RETURNS text AS
$BODY$

BEGIN
return to_char($1, '9.999');
END;

$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE  COST 100;
```

But it pads the value with leading spaces. How can I get this working? I have tried `'.999'` in the `to_char` call but that doesn't work either, yielding `.###`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would simple cast to [an arbitrary precision number](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) work for you?

```
SELECT 0.3456::numeric(4,3);
```

Same inside a function (btw, better use `SQL` functions, as optimizer can inline them):

```
CREATE FUNCTION ff(float) RETURNS numeric(4,3) AS $ff$
    SELECT $1::numeric(4,3);
$ff$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: Yup, that'll do. A lot easier :)